# How many Jedi learned Darth Vader's identity during the Jedi Purge?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, darth-vader

Ahsoka Tano learned of Darth Vader's identity when she was near him.

Surely other Jedi learned his true name when they were near him, perhaps moments before they died.

Is there any record of other Jedi learning Darth Vader's identity by sensing him when they were nearby?

I am looking for answers from G-canon or T-canon, not lower canon levels.

Comment: She had been training with him for a long time, and thus might have recognized him through the Force more easily than some random Jedi.

Comment: @Adamant - given Vader's dialogue about Obi-Wan in ANH, that theory makes good sense.

Comment: Obi-Wan and Yoda both learned it at the end of RotS

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that the original plan, before Anakin had to don the Vader suit to stay alive, appears to have been for there to be no secret and everybody who saw Vader would know just by looking at him that he was Anakin, similar to how Count Dooku was treated. But it seems Palpatine decided that having a mysterious enforcer was better. Maybe he thought that hunting down the Jedi while having a former Jedi as his right hand man would send mixed messages.

### Disney Canon

- Obi-Wan Kenobi (found out by examining footage of the Jedi Temple massacre, personally made him require the suit)
- Yoda (sensed it, confirmed through footage of the Jedi Temple massacre)
- Ahsoka (sensed Anakin's presence while being told by another that it was Vader)
- Luke Skywalker (was told by Darth Vader himself)

It's not entirely clear how Obi-Wan and Yoda knew that Anakin and the "more machine now than man" Darth Vader were one and the same, but I'll chalk that up to meditating on the Force.

In all of these cases, the individuals chose to keep this information to themselves, likely due to their personal connection to Vader, and to not encourage anti-Jedi sentiment by revealing that a Jedi war hero became a foreboding, ruthless agent of evil.

### Legends

In addition to Obi-Wan, Yoda, and Luke, we also have:

- [Roan Shryne](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Roan_Shryne) and [Olee Starstone](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Olee%20Starstone)

  - The two were at the Jedi Temple massacre and escaped. Roan was killed by Vader and Olee decided to live a life of anonymity like Obi-Wan and Yoda.
- [An'ya Kuro/The Dark Woman](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/An%27ya_Kuro)

  - After being killed by Vader, she reappeared as a force ghost and told Vader that he could still become Anakin again. It's not clear how she knew they were one and the same.

Also, the official story from Palpatine is that Anakin Skywalker died during the Jedi Temple massacre, and it seems that the story stuck. The clones from the 501st Legion obviously knew his identity since they marched in with him, but it doesn't seem like they told anyone (and the *Battlefront II* story campaign shows that they weren't just killed off to keep the secret, but continued fighting for the Empire).

Comment: To reinforce some of your "probably" as facts: Obi Wan initially believed Anakin dead (in every point of view) though he had been worried the latter survived. In the immediate months, though, he heard rumours about the rise of a new dark menace to the top of the newly christened Imperial army. He eventually learnt that this Terminator-ish figure (in my own words) is known as Darth Vader. That's how he learnt that Anakin survived (from the physical point of view).

Comment: As for keeping Vader's true identity a secret: During the Clone Wars, Palpatine had repeatedly emphasised on Dooku being a former Jedi in his public speeches in a subtle move to turn public approval against the Jedi. So yes, if Yoda had learnt anything from this, he would think it prudent not to let it be known that Vader is another former Jedi, and arguably their greatest one to boot.